# How do i get rid of value error, the view xxx didn't return an HttpResponse Object. It returned none instead

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, cs50

so im doing cs50x web development and the assignment is creating a wikipedia page. I created a views function where I can click on edit page to edit the content. However I keep running into this problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rudAD.png)

This is my code from views.py

```py
class EditForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(label= "Body")

def edit_page(request):
    title = request.POST.get("edit")
    body = util.get_entry(title)
    form = EditForm(initial={'body': body})
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data["body"]
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/title.html", {
                "title": title, "content": util.get_entry(title)
            })  
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "form": EditForm()
        })
```

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.title, name="title"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("new_page", views.new_page, name="new_page"),
    path("random", views.randomizer, name="random"),
    path("edit", views.edit_page, name="edit")
]
```

title.html:

```html
<form action= "{% url 'edit' %}", method= "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="edit" value="{{title}}" id="edit">Edit Page</button>
    </form>
```

and finally edit.html

```html
<form action="{% url 'edit' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Someone please help me to solve this issue thanks!

Comment: You never return a response if the form is invalid. (You have returned a response if the form is valid but haven't done anything if that is false)

Answer (score 0):

form = EditForm(request.POST or None ,initial={'body': body})

Comment: i still get the same error after changing my code to this